# Disable search cache in OpenSearchServer

Tags: caching, open-source, opensearch

I have OpenSearchServer (OSS) set up on my local web server. I see that there is a Search Cache that the application automatically applies. Unfortunately, this means that when I make requests using the following URL http://example.com/renderer?use=filecrawl&name=default-file&query=blue, it just searches and returns results from a previous query. It won't find matches for current query "blue." This does not seem to be a consistent problem. I noticed that after flushing the Search Cache, it then started working as it should be. But, I think that this is going to become an issue for me often. I do not want to have to flush the Search Cache. I just want to turn it off. Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable search cache by setting its "Max size" to 0, as shown in attached image.

[See image: disabling search cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eZMn.png)

Regards,
Alexandre!